# Notice: Array to string conversion on PDO's execute()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm busy building some new stuff, and I wanted to use PDO. Just that little but extra, you know. So i got the first things working, and now I ran into the following error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\classes\class.page.php on line 25
```

I find myself wondering why I got this, since I read the code for like 15 times, and I just couldn't figure it out..

Here's a piece of `class.page.php`

```
    $query = DB::$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1'); \\ 23
    $query->bindParam(':id', $pageid, \PDO::PARAM_INT); // 24
    $query->execute(); // 25
    $pageInfo = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // 26
```

To me, this just seems like a regular PDO statement.. What's the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the content of `$pageid`?

Comment: @juergend After `var_dump`, this is the output: `string(1) "1"`

Comment: Why did you add a backslash in the `fetch` method? [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) says the following: `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: @Arcturil Since I use Namespacing. Otherwise it throws an error

Comment: @RobinBerg : delete the \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC in braces. And try without.

Comment: Can we see the content of $pageInfo? It has some empty key?

Comment: instead of `\PDO::PARAM_INT` and `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` can you pass `1 & 2` respectively.  your code looks completely fine to me just for a test

Comment: also can you share the error it throw if you remove \ from PDO::PARAM_INT

Comment: @yiiframe `Warning: include_once(C:/xampp2/htdocs\application\classes\class.pdo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\bootstrap.php on line 18` As I said, it'll trigger an error because of the namespacing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retrieve the value of `$pageid` from superglobal `$_POST` , you have to also define the key :

```
$pageid['..'] 


$query->bindParam(':id', $pageid['..'], \PDO::PARAM_INT); // 24
```

and remove that `\` token in front of the `PDO` you don't need it anyway